# How to denote a sequence indexed by another sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, notation

Lets say I have two corresponding finite sequences $A = (3, 4, 6, 1)$ and $B = (x_3, x_4, x_6, x_1)$, and a space $C$ such that $x_i \in C$ for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can I denote $B$ in terms of $A$? The expression
$$
B = (x_i)_{i \in A}
$$
would be convenient, but, presumably incorrect, since $\in$ isn't used for sequences.

Comment: You could write $B=\langle x_{A_i}:1\le i\le|A|\rangle$.

Comment: You could introduce a notation for the image $D = \{3, 4, 6, 1\}$ of the sequence $A,$ and write $B = (x_i)_{i \in D}.$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the *[projection map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics))*
\begin{align*}
&\pi_k:X^n\to X\qquad\qquad\qquad 1\leq k\leq n\\
&(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\to x_k\tag{1}
\end{align*}
to extract the $k$-th component of an $n$-tuple $(x_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}$.

> Using (1) we can write OPs example as
> \begin{align*}
> B=\left(x_{\pi_{k}(A)}\right)_{1\leq k\leq |A|}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* With respect to ease readability it might be more convenient to simply write:

Let $A=(a_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}$. We consider $B=\left(x_{a_j}\right)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ ...